# AWS SAM Global setting for MemorySize is not used in Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, sam

I am using eclipse to create a Serverless Application. In trying to Clean up my deployment template I am attempting to use Globals. However, I find that the memory size attribute is ignored when deploying my Java function.

Below is a section from my SAM Template:

```
"Globals":{
"Function": {
  "Tags" : {
    "Client" : { "Ref": "Client"},
    "Stage" : { "Ref" : "NameExt" }
  },
  "Runtime" : "java8",
  "MemorySize" : "1024",
  "Timeout" : 300,
  "Environment" : {
    "Variables" : {
      "REGION" : { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" },
      "STAGE" : { "Ref" : "NameExt" }
    }
  }
}
},
"Resources": {
"RunReports" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::Serverless::Function",
  "Properties" : {
    "Handler" : "APIReports",
    "FunctionName" : "RunReport",
    "Policies" :  [ "AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess", "AmazonS3FullAccess" ],
    "Events" : {
      "GetResource" : {
        "Type" : "Api",
        "Properties" : {
          "Path" : "/commands/report",
          "Method" : "Get"
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
},
```

When the project is Deployed, using eclipse, the MemorySize of the Function is set to 512.

Any help, greatly appreciated.
Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're just about there, you only need to make one small adjustment.  I just took a look at a SAM `template.yaml` file I have and converted it to json with [this nifty tool](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cfn-template-flip).

Anyhow, the issue appears to be with the value of the `Memory` property being a string.  Drop the surrounding quotes and you should be fine.

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Transform": "AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31",
    "Description": "Something really descriptive",
    "Globals": {
        "Function": {
            "Timeout": 120,
            "MemorySize": 256
        }
    },
```

Hope this helps.